# LED and Fluorescent Lights

Tags: power

With all the LED and fluorescent light bulbs being used now and much more later, do you expect  power companies to raise rates because of lower power factor? Or will they just absorb the cost as they are doing now? Or will they add a device to the meter to measure VAs? It's not much per household but millions of households added together......

Answer (score 1):

Regulations for essentially all countries require electronic products to conform to (international ) standards which specify power factor requirements and allowed waveform distortion. In some countries the management and enforcement of such regulations may be lax for whatever reasons, but in most administrations compliance is enforced or reasonably expected.

Modern electronic energy meters which are in widespread domestic use in many countries are able to measure KVA, kW, RMS voltage and current and more. Any new electronic meter is almost certain to have this capability.

Even low cost plug in energy meters (most of Asian manufacture) have full capability in this area as it mainly requires the use of a complex but reasonably priced IC. Such a meter is typically as inherently accurate as a house energy meter with processing capabilities of better than 0.1% accuracy - actual resultant accuracy is determined by the stability of the (usually resistive) current shunt and voltage measuring resistive divider. Initial errors can be calibrated out - so long term stability becomes "of interest".